# Parsing JSON hierarchy

Tags: ios, json

I'm still trying (I already asked a few question about this) to parse my own JSON file. Here is my JSON :

```
{
"album":[
        {
            "album_titre":"PublicitÃ©",
            "album_photo":"blabla.jpg",
            "album_videos":[
                           {
                               "titre_video":"Chauffage Compris",
                               "duree_video":"01'25''",
                               "photo_video":"chauffage.jpg",
                               "lien_video":"www.bkjas.jhas.kajs"
                           },
                           {
                               "titre_video":"NIFFF 2012",
                               "duree_video":"01'43''",
                               "photo_video":"nifff.jpg",
                               "lien_video":"www.bkjas.jhas.kajs"
                           }
                           ]
        },
        {
           "album_titre":"Events",
           "album_photo":"bloublou.jpg",
           "album_videos":[
                          {
                               "titre_video":"Auvernier Jazz",
                               "duree_video":"01'15''",
                               "photo_video":"auvernier.jpg",
                               "lien_video":"www.bkjas.jhas.kajs"
                           },
                           {
                               "titre_video":"NIFFF 2011",
                               "duree_video":"01'03''",
                               "photo_video":"nifff2011.jpg",
                               "lien_video":"www.bkjas.jhas.kajs"
                           }
                           ]
      }
      ]
}
```

With help of community, I've made this :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


     dispatch_async (kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:lienAlbumsVideo];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

     NSError* error;
     NSDictionary *document = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

     if (document==nil)
    {
         NSLog( @"oops\n%@", error);
    }

     NSArray *album = document[@"album"];

     NSMutableArray *album_titre = [NSMutableArray new];
     NSMutableArray *album_photo = [NSMutableArray new];
     NSMutableArray *album_videos = [NSMutableArray new];

     for( NSDictionary *elementOnRoot in album )
    {
        [album_titre addObject:elementOnRoot[@"album_titre"]];
        [album_photo addObject:elementOnRoot[@"album_photo"]];
        [album_videos addObject:elementOnRoot[@"album_videos"]];
    }

     NSLog(@"%@", [album_titre objectAtIndex:0]);
     NSLog(@"%@", [album_videos objectAtIndex:1]);
     NSLog(@"%@", album_photo);

}
```

Now, I'm a bit mixed up with structure. My question is how (using my actual Xcode) can I have a list (NSArray or dictionary) of "titre_video", "duree_video", "photo_video" and "lien_video"?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my basic xcode level...

Nicolas

Comment: The JSON structure is reflected almost exactly in the structure of the objects produced by the parser.  Look at json.org to understand the syntax (it's very simple and you can take it all in in 5 minutes).  Once you know how to read the syntax then "peeling the onion" to get at a particular bit of data is quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for( NSDictionary *albumDic in album )
{
    for( NSDictionary *album_videosDic in albumDic[@"album_videos"])
    {
        [album_titre addObject:album_videosDic[@"titre_video"]];
        [album_videos addObject:album_videosDic[@"duree_video"]];
        [album_photo  addObject:album_videosDic[@"photo_video"]];
    }
}
```